# Filter to the magento admin grid column with renderer value

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, filter, custom-grid

I got stuck into the magento admin grid. I need to put the filter on the grid column. which has value YES and NO.

But YES and NO are decided from the many conditions. I have one renderer file for delivering the value for column and in that file there are lots of conditions. By passing through lots of conditions I have decided that particular row should have YES/No or BLANK.

And I don't know how to put a filter above the column. I cant put the same logic to the **filter callback** as there are already around 200 lines conditions have been put to the renderer files.

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Thank you.

Here is my code
Grid.php

```
$this->addColumn('mailSent', array(
        'header'            => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Other Updates'),
        'renderer'          => 'Namesapce_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Vendor_Order_Renderer_Mailsent',
        'option'            => $this->getVendorIds(),
        'type'              => 'options',
        'options'           => Mage::getModel('vendor/vendor')->getOptionArray(),
        'column_css_class'  => 'mailsent-td',
        'width'             => '4px'
));
```

Comment: Put your code which you are trying

Comment: @RahulSingh I have edited the question. Please let me know if you want renderer file code. You can imagine the renderer file with many conditions and in results it returns YES/NO/BLANK. as per requirement.

Comment: The code must be adding column "Other Updates"  and with the option (filter) on grid, Till here you getting or not ?

Comment: Yes I am getting the column values perfectly having dropdown to the the top saying YES/NO.. I dont know how to make this dropdown working.  like selecting yes - it should return the rows having YES only.

Comment: have you checked Renderer file is it working ?

Comment: 'index' => ?? missing in addColumn

Comment: yeah.. its working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use filter callback like below:

```
'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_myCustomFilter')
```

And add this function to your grid.php file and put the conditions according to your requirement.

```
protected function _myCustomFilter($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
        "my_field like ?"
    , "%$value%");


    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cant do this as my column value is not based on the collection . I cant get grid values for that particular column by simply putting "where conditions".  I m having lots of conditions and then its decided that YES/NO value for the column..

Comment: You need to join the queries.

Comment: result is not bases on DB - there are some constant declared and other array manipulations with color code for every status. which increases line of code at renderer file